# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' with laravel and angular js

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, ubuntu-16.04

I used Angular js for frontend application and for backend i used `laravel 5.2`, I already install `cors` origin allowed in my project 
because all data transfer very good, but when I upload images using 
`ajax` and `base64`, then I get this message from my browser:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.api.panakeias.com/updateTeacherpicprofile/9. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

I deployed my two project on digital ocean LEMP Stack Ubuntu 16.04
 frontend project is on main domain and backend project is on sub-domain.

Comment: *The response had HTTP status code 500.* means there’s some server-side failure on your backend that’s unrelated to your CORS config. The only reason you’re seeing that CORS message is either because the server failure occurs before it ever hits that, or else like many or most server systems, it doesn’t send the `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers in error responses. Anyway, you need to look through your PHP or whatever logs on the server side and see what message is getting logged about the cause of that 500 internal failure in the server

Comment: message  500 internal server error is getting empty and when test on post man still  getting empty ..!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add this code on top of your route.php:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, X-Requested-With,  Content-Type, Accept");
```

Comment: does your brosers an option request before the real request? and you receive the data after that ?

Comment: I send and receive data very good and receive images very good 
only my problem when post or put new image to my host

Comment: when you load this url : http://www.api.panakeias.com/updateTeacherpicprofile/9  check in the console in network tab, what is the value of response header for this: Access-Control-Allow-Origin:

Comment: Copy + pasted from another answer with no explanation, also you gave no explanation of what these headers are doing, or the side effects. this is reckless to say the least.

Comment: Ohgodwhy what is explanation ??